# Moving window algorithm

Tags: algorithm

Say I have an array of `n` integers, `m`, each chosen randomly from the range `[x,y]`.

I also have a window of fixed size `[a,b]`, and smaller than `[x,y]` such that `b-a < x-y`.

Starting from an arbitrary window position, can anyone think of a good algorithm to use to determine whether it is possible for the window to be moved such that all elements of `m` are enclosed within the window?

Comment: You are using x twice with different meanings, very confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just get the `minimum` and `maximum` number from the array `m` and see if they fit in the `[a,b]` interval? Maybe I don't get the meaning of the `window` thing.

Comment: Your were just 30 seconds faster than me with that answer.

Comment: Actually, although this is the correct answer to my question above, it isn't the answer to the question I meant to ask! I think I'll have to post a new (rephrased) question.

Comment: @Dunnie - `OK` and please include an example this time:)

Comment: Don't worry Doc, you can just get into your DeLorean :)