# Double moving window algorithm

Tags: algorithm

Say I have an array of `n` integers, `m`, each chosen randomly from the range `[x,y]`.

I also have two windows of fixed size `[a,b]` and `[c,d]`. The windows follow these rules:

- `d-a < y-x` i.e. the total range of the windows is smaller than that of `[x,y]`;
- `c > b`
- `c-b = const` i.e. the two windows are always fixed distance apart.

Starting from an arbitrary window position, can anyone think of a good algorithm to use to determine whether it is possible for the two windows to be moved such that all elements of `m` are enclosed within the windows?

Here are some examples:

a) Let `m = { 20, 21, 23, 25, 26, 27, 28 }`, the size of both windows is 4, and `c-b = 2`. There is a solution here, with `a = 20, b = 23, c = 25, d = 28`.

b) Using the same `m`, but with `c-b = 3`, there isn't a solution which doesn't cause one element of `m` to fall between the two windows.

I was thinking along the lines of implementing a golden section search of some description to find the best solution, but there's a good chance I'm mission something obvious here.

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Comment: This should probably be merged with [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7162543/moving-window-algorithm).

Answer (score 1):

Sort your elements. You get the sorted list x1,x2,...,xm, where x1 is the smallest. For each i check whether (x{i+1} - xi) is larger than c-b. If so, check whether (xi-x1) is smaller than b-a and whether (xm-x{i+1}) is smaller than d-c, and (xm-x1) is smaller than d-a. If all these conditions hold, there is a solution where the first window covers x1 .. xi and the second window covers x{i+1}...xm. It remains find the exact location of the gap between xi and x_{i+1}. Let the gap begin at g=min(xi+(b-a), x{i+1}-(c-b)) and end at g'=g+(c-b). Then g >= xi, g'<= x{i+1}, g-a >= xi-x1 and d-g' >= xm-x{i+1}.

Comment: Good answer, but you're not looking at the problem from the correct angle; I don't want to verify whether the elements fit in a given window, I'm looking for an algorithm to find the windows themselves.

Comment: I see. Then you can tweak this algorithm: if the condition on c-b holds, the windows are (xi-x1) and (xm-x{i+1}). Pick the best ones.

Comment: Sorry, I clearly haven't explained myself very well! For any set of elements, the window constraints are already known, i.e. b-a, c-b, and d-c are constant. So the algorithm needs to find the values of a,b,c,d given the above constraints.

Comment: There are many possible values. Do you want all of them, or is there a criteria to choose which is the best?

Comment: @Irit I don't think your solution is right: let's take m={1,3,8,10} and b-a = 3; c-b =1 and c-d = 3 then between 3 and 8 you have : 8-3 > b-c , 3-1 <b-a and 10-8 < d-c but there is no solution around these points (8 and 3)... tell me if I missed something. I think you need to add a test to correct your algorithm

Comment: Ricky: You're right. You need to check, in addition, that xm-x1 is not more than d-a. Does this fix it?

Comment: @Irit, I gave +1 but I think you should elaborate a little bit on how to get to an actual solution. Once you know that a solution exists, centered on between Xi and Xi+1 give more detail on how to get to a window that fits. (may be iterate for b=xi to b=xi+1-(c-b) until you find one solution)

Comment: Thanks, I added that bit. I still don't know what Dunnie was asking for though!

Answer (score 0):

Given any solution, you can always nudge it to the right until the leftmost edge of one of the two windows just touches a point. So the possible solutions start with the leftmost window on a point, or at a fixed offset from a point, because the right window is on a point.

So you can start with the leftmost possible solution and work out where the window boundaries should be. If it is a match, you're done. If not, slide the window right to the next possible solution and check that. Each such slide costs you the effort of moving pointers and noting when they cross the location of a point. Each point sees each pointer only once, so the total cost should be linear in the number of points - if they are given in sorted order, or the n log n cost of sorting those points if they are not.